# Javascript - Next line executes before call back completes

Tags: callback

I have an html file where i am including 2 js in its head. The first.js has a getJSON call and a call back function to it as below:

```
    finalResult = ""
callbackfunction = function(result){
    finalResult = some manipulation with result
}
getJSON (url, callbackfunction)
```

The second.js is using the data 'finalResult' of first.js. Something like below:

```
ultimateResult = some manipulation with finalResult
```

Issue: The line ultimateResult gets executed before the callback function is invoked and hence second.js always reads finalResult as blank value.

I tried setting the ajax asynch variable to false before making the json call --> Dint help
I tried including script of first.js in to second.js to execute it before the line of ultimate script --> Dint help
I cannot include second.js ultimateResult script in to callback of first.js --> This is not an option for me

I can compromise on performance where ultimateResult can wait for call back to complete but i am not sure how do i implement it. The program loops if i try to use some flag with while condition (of course).

Thank you!

Comment: Call ultimateResult from inside the callback?

Comment: thanks for the response. Unfortunately this is not an option for me, i have mentioned this in the description :)

Answer (score 0):

So you have:

HTML:

```
<script src="first.js"></script>
<script src="second.js"></script>
```

first.js:

```
var finalResult = '';
var callBackFunction = function(result) {
  finalResult = codeManipulation();
}
getJson(url, callBackFunction);
```

second.js:

```
function ultimateResult(result) {
  console.log(result);
}
ultimateResult(finalResult);

//OUTPUTS EMPTY STRING
```

- You could use promises instead of a callback.This is the recommended approach
- You could fire an event when the value is returned that ultimateResult is watching for
- You could have initially set the value of finalResult to undefined and check the value in a recursive loop until it is defined.
- VERY BAD IDEA, DO NOT DO THIS: put a timeout on calling ultimateResult.  This is bad because if the call comes back before the API you are wasting time.  It is even worse when the call takes longer than expected because the value will come back as an empty string if it has not been return by the time it is called.